# Stack navigator back navigation not working properly

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am facing a strange behaviour in stack navigator back navigation.I have a homepage of application with some icons, clicking on icons opens a new page. Which further have pages inside.
Home->Icon1->Page1->Page2->Page3 like this.

On home Screen, I have added a BackHandler to ask for exiting the application or not instead of directly exiting the application. Whenever I come back from other screens to Home screen it does not ask for the option. It works only when rendering is happening and incase of back navigation I don't think that rendering happens again. If I add BackHandler on inside pages, they simply do not work. So I am confused how to handle the back navigation with StackNavigator.

Code to handle back android button on home screen. Removing the listener while navigating to other screens. If app is opened and I press back button then it this handler is called, But when I navigate to other screens and come back to home then this handler is not called and app exits directly without showing the prompt.

```
    componentDidMount() {
        SplashScreen.close({animationType: SplashScreen.animationType.fade, duration: 2000, delay: 500})
        if (Platform.OS == "android") {
          BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
        }
      }

  handleBackButton = () => {
    var route = this.props.navigation.state.routeName;
    if(route == 'LoginPage')
    {
    Alert.alert('Exit App', 'Exiting the application?', [
      {
        text: 'No',
        onPress: () => console.log('Cancel Pressed'),
        style: 'cancel'
      }, {
        text: 'Yes',
        onPress: () => BackHandler.exitApp()
      }
    ], {cancelable: false})
  }
    return true;
  }

<TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={.5}
                onPress={() => {
                BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
                navigate("LiveTV")
              }}>
```

Comment: Please add [mcve] and give some more context about _not work_ part. Do you get any errors or what sort of unexpected behavior you are getting etc.

Comment: I have added the code , please check

Comment: You are removing listener `onPress`. When you navigate back to screens with `goBack` screens don't re-render, so the handler doesn't add back.

Comment: But if I don't remove listener then pressing back button same listener is called on other screens also and it shows prompt to exit the app or not, which I want to show only on home screens.

Comment: You can keep the handler and check the routeName from the navigation. If its the one you want you can proceed with the alert if not

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Can you tell me how to get current route name in stack navigator

Comment: `this.props.navigation.state.routeName`

Comment: Hi I tried this , but it is not working. I added the condition for homepage. But it is again calling on all the screens.

Comment: Please update your question with the second implementation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158673/discussion-between-paras-watts-and-bennygenel).

Comment: I have updated the code

Comment: Have you checked the code

Comment: What does it says when you logged route right before the if statement?

Comment: LoginPage it prints in the log

Comment: When I pressed back on the next screen then again it printed the route name LoginPage

Comment: Ok my logic is not applicable here I think. You may need to add similar logic but not sure what

Comment: I have removed the listener in componentWillUnmount and sometimes it works and sometimes it does not.